# Unusual Transconductance Equation

Tags: transistors, cmos, manufacturing-process

I am a math-heavy electronics noob, and I was [reading a paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251308865_An_automatic_procedure_for_the_synthesis_and_optimization_of_very_low-frequency_G_m_-C_integrators) when I came across this equation:

$$g_m=\frac{2 I_D}{\left(V_{G S}-V_{T H}\right)}\left[1-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\theta_1\left(V_{G S}-V_{T H}\right)}{1+\theta_1\left(V_{G S}-V_{T H}\right)}\right]$$

The paper references Tsividis' Operation and Modeling of The MOS Transistor [2 ed.], but it's not exactly clear where in the 600-page book on MOSFETs one could find this equation especially when its defining term \$\theta_1\$ isn't defined in the symbol key.

Is anyone familiar with this equation? What is it used for... how do I compute \$\theta_1\$ for a given process?

Comment: Welcome. `I was reading a paper ...` When referring to a document/article/webpage, it's good to put a link to the source so others can better understand what you are referring to. If this is not possible, it's acceptable to give a name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, updated!

Comment: Any clue about operating region i.e. linear or saturation? I assume it's saturation because \$I_D\$ appears, though.

Comment: Good hint is: considering the vertical field mobility degeneration, ID in saturation region and strong inversion, can be written as: \$I_D=\frac{\beta}{1+\theta_1\left(V_{G S}-V_{T H}\right)} \frac{\left(V_{G S}-V_{T H}\right)^2}{2 \alpha}\$

Comment: Well, from what I know, saturation current is \$I_D=\mu \ C_{ox} \ (W/L) \ (V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2\$. Now if we take the partial derivative w.r.t. \$V_{GS}\$ we'll get \$g_m= 2 \ I_D / (V_{GS}-V_{TH})\$. This fits the first part of the equation you have in the question. So, apparently, \$\theta_1\$ is a very small, unitless constant to approximate the part in square brackets 1. Sorry, I have no idea but, could it be related to the physical dimensions maybe?

Comment: Yeah, it looks similar to an equation that I've seen before for mobility degradation \$I_D = \frac{\mu_n C_{ox} (W/L)V_{eff}^2}{2[1+(\theta V_{eff}^m)]^{1/m}}\$ but this specific form is quite different - I guess I could use this one where I know how to compute its values instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might be referring to the SPICE level-3 parameter.

Shockingly, the equations can be found in the direct online source: 
[*The Simulation of MOS Integrated Circuits Using SPICE2*, Vladimirescu and Liu, EECS Department University of California, Berkeley, Technical Report No. UCB/ERL M80/7, February 1980](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1980/9610.html)

On page 28 (34):

[image: Surface Mobility Modulation by Gate Voltage]

and page 32 (38):

[image: THETA Mobility Modulation Parameter]

It's not clear to me if this explains what you were looking at (was it in regards to MOSFET threshold or mobility, or modeling, perhaps in SPICE?).  In any case, this reference is worth including for posterity, and may answer many questions around physical interpretation and modeling of these components.

Comment: So, it's a mobility degradation equation, I guess these just change as people try to improve their models. Engineering is taking some getting used to, hah